# Only query for date objects in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
╔════╦══════╦════════════╦═════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║  BIRTHDAY  ║ AGE ║  DEATHDAY  ║
╠════╬══════╬════════════╬═════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ JIM  ║ 10/20/1942 ║  70 ║ 11/21/2012 ║
║  2 ║ BOB  ║ 01/11/1930 ║  60 ║ 02/11/1990 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════════╩═════╩════════════╝
```

Say I have a table like above, and I want to make a **query** to get **all DATE values** where id = 1 in a table. So something like:

```
Select * from peopleinfo where id = 1 and value.type = DATE;
```

Obviously, **value.type isn't valid SQL**, but here's what I've found that might be helpful:

```
(SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'PEOPLEINFO' and data_type = 'DATE')
```

This gives me a list of all the date columns in the table. However, I'm not sure how to use that to my ends. Please let me know if you have suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by this.  If you know what table you're accessing then you know the schema and can therefore select the proper columns by name, which will be much more efficient than selecting the columns by data type.  Are you running dynamic queries or is the schema changing all the time?  Also, is this for MYSQL or Oracle?

Comment: Well the reason is because I want to run this over multiple tables. So the easiest thing would be to have something to tell me which columns are date fields so I don't have to do that manually. And it's for Oracle, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the information from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` to build a dynamic query and then bind and execute it using functions in the `DBMS_SQL` package but I can tell you that this is a lot of work to go through. Perhaps this might be worthwhile if you have a real business need for this sort of functionality, or if you're interested in it as a challenge.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want this eludes me, but to create "dynamic sql" you use SQL queries that return valid sql statements. Then you execute those. e.g.

```
    select
        'select ' ||
        listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by 1)
        || ' from PEOPLEINFO  where id=1'
    from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'PEOPLEINFO'
    and data_type = 'DATE'
```

and the result of that query will look like this:

```
SQL_STMT
select BIRTHDAY,DEATHDAY from PEOPLEINFO where id=1
```

Thereafter you use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run the created statement(s)

I suggest you read about it (e.g. [Performing SQL Operations with Native Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm)). Please do note that dynamic sql is potentially a security threat (by malicious sql being inserted and then executed).